# is there a way to delete my databse row using a button and php

Tags: php, html

I created a table with my PHP and database and added a delete button on the right of each of my element in my first column and I want this button to delete the row in my database but I don't know how to link my button to a PHP action

```php
<table border="2" class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
        <th scope="col"><h6>Nom de l'Etape</h6></th>
        <th scope="col"><h6>Description de l'Etape </h6> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>


      <?php
      $req='SELECT * FROM Etape';
      $resultat=$dbh->query($req);

      while ($ligne=$resultat->fetch()) {
        echo "<tr> <td>". $ligne[0]."<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"alert('Hello world!')\">delete</button></td><td>".$ligne[1]."</td>  </tr>";
      }

       ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Yes you should use ajax. There are good examples online this site if you search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use ajax:

```
<?php
   // Check if is background ajax query or user just enter page

  // Is background ajax query, run PHP code
  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'):
      // RUN PHP CODE IN BACKGROUND (IN YOUR CASE: DELETE ROW FROM DB)
  else: 
  // Is not ajax query - show HTML page
?>

    <table border="2" class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
        <th scope="col"><h6>Nom de l'Etape</h6></th>
        <th scope="col"><h6>Description de l'Etape </h6> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
       // Your PHP function to get button from database
       $req='SELECT * FROM Etape';
       $resultat=$dbh->query($req);
       while ($ligne=$resultat->fetch()) {
          echo '<tr> <td>'. $ligne[0].'<button type="button" value="<?php echo $ligne[0]; ?>">delete</button></td><td>'.$ligne[1].'</td></tr>';
       }
     ?>
    </table>
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
<script>
// Button click
$(document).on('click','button',function(e) {

   // Get button value
   var my_id = $(this).val();

   // Prepare ajax query
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType:"json",
      // Set url to file itself
      url: window.location.href,
      // set data
      data: "id=" + my_id,
      beforeSend: function (data) {
           alert('Sending');
      },
      success: function (data) 
      {
          alert('Success');
      },
      error: function (data) 
      {
          alert('Error');
      }
    });     
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: why you use ajax for delete the database row

Comment: Ajax allows you to pass value (row id to delete in this case) in the background (without refreshing the page). After you execute your delete command in PHP.

Comment: can you write simpler or explain delete part (if block of code).

Comment: I think there is no simpler code to do this ...I have added comments to the code above, I hope they will help ...

Comment: If this answer is useful for You, please mark it as correct.

Comment: thank I just want to know where I should put my sql command to delete My row and the only thing I don't understand is your if condition ?

Comment: I tried to pu this under ```$req2='DELETE FROM `Etape` WHERE `Etape`.`NomEtape` = \'Mygame_typeFullGame_test2\'';
 $resultat=$dbh->query($req2);```
what should I put to replace "Mygame_typeFullGame_test2"

Comment: In this case, simple: `$req2='DELETE FROM Etape WHERE id='.$_POST['id']`. Remember that for a security reason you need to escape  $_POST variable string. PHP ref: [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: hum sorry but it seems that it dosen't work when I press the delete but a dialog sending open and when I click ok it just send me an error dialog box